# 'cb.apply is not a function' error running 'npx react-native init'

Tags: react-native, linux-mint

I want to learn React Native, so i read documents in [Offical Site](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) and I install some softwares. I installed JDK, Android Studio, NodeJs, Watchman..

At the least, When i use this command:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

I got error:

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
```

I tried to graceful, but it didn't work.

```
npm install graceful-fs --save-dev
```

So what should I do ?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.

Comment: Did you check [it](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874#issuecomment-663661148)?

Answer (score 0):

you most install npm:

- install `npm`

than install `react-native` :

- `npm install -g`
  `react-native-cli && npm install -g react-native` (admin or sudo)

then for create project use:

- `react-native init MyProject`

than go to project folder with :

- `cd Myproject`

and finally use this for run project:

- `react-native run-ios` or `run-android`